# for the right syntax to use near 'DESC' at line 1

Tags: mysql-error-1064

for the right syntax to use near 'DESC' at line 1 in python

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
import mysql.connector
from pandas import *
mySQLconnection = mysql.connector.connect(database='demo',user='root',password='9999')
cursor = mySQLconnection .cursor()
sql="select * from supplierdatabase DESC"

cursor.execute(sql)

data1=cursor.fetchall()
print (data1)
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''.................

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to order the results but haven't said which column you'd like to order the results on.

You need to add an `ORDER BY` clause to your SQL statement. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM supplierdatabase ORDER BY suppliername DESC
```

You need to use whatever field name is appropriate for your situation.